# Left ordered binary matrix algorithm in R

Tags: r, algorithm, binary-data

I'm trying to produce an algorithm (a function preferably in R) to order any binary matrix by colomn at left as this :

First, it is important to mention that the function just order the columns. We are not able to move a specific value without move all the column. Any row is move also. This function is obtained by ordering the columns of the binary matrix from left to right by the magnitude of the binary number expressed by that column, taking the first row as the most significant bit.

Example : Suppose I have a matrix as $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&1&0&1&0\
1&1&0&1&0&1&0\
0&1&1&0&1&0&0\
0&1&1&1&1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and I want to transform it in $\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&0&0&0&0\
1&1&1&1&0&0&0\
0&0&0&1&1&1&0\
1&0&0&1&1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$

In fact, I order the first row by taking all the columns with 1 first.
In row 2, between the columns with 1 at the first row, I order the column that has 1 first and I do the same between the column with 0 at the first row.
and so one till the last row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One only needs to deal with the numeric values of the columns of the matrix and properly order the columns using the *order* function suitably as the second argument in the '[ , ]' matrix operator. Here it goes:

```
    # vect is a binary vector
    # returns the value of the vector
    to.value <- function(vect){
       L <- length(vect)
       value <- 0
       for (i in L:1){
           value <- value + 2^(L-i)*vect[i]
      }
      return(value)
  }

  # matrix is a square binary matrix
  # returns the values of the columns in a vector

 column.values <- function(matrix){
     result <- numeric(ncol(matrix))
     for (i in 1:length(result)){
       result[i] <- to.value(matrix[,i])
    }
    return(result)
}

    # matrix is a square binary matrix
    # returns the matrix in the prescribed order

   get.ordered.matrix <- function(matrix){
      vals <- column.values(mat)
      return(matrix[,rev(order(vals))])
  }

    ### Test ###

 l <- 8
 set.seed(20)
 mat <- matrix(floor(runif(l^2,min=0,max=2)),ncol=l)
 mat
 get.ordered.matrix(mat)
```

Comment: Excellent. It's work perfectly. Using the value as you defined it is "super". Thanks