# Python - Left Ordered Binary Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a binary matrix of N rows and K columns. I would like to reorder the matrix into "left-ordered form," meaning the columns are permuted such that if each column is treated as a number in binary format (with the first row's value as most significant bit and the last row's value as the least significant bit), the columns are in decreasing value from left to right. For instance, this would look like the following:

```
[[0, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0]]
```

becomes

```
[[1, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1]]
```

This question is the same as [Left ordered binary matrix algorithm in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345425/left-ordered-binary-matrix-algorithm-in-r), but the answer there is insufficient. I have no upper bound on the number of rows N, so explicitly computing each column's binary value is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt bucket sort to sort it row by row until there's nothing left to sort.

```
import numpy as np

sample = np.array([
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
])

def SortMatrix(matrix, indices, row):
    if indices.size <= 1 or row >= matrix.shape[0]:
        return indices
    left = indices[np.where(matrix[row, indices] == 1)]
    right = indices[np.where(matrix[row, indices] == 0)]
    return np.concatenate((SortMatrix(matrix, left, row+1), SortMatrix(matrix, right, row+1)))

sample = sample[:,SortMatrix(sample, np.array(range(sample.shape[1])), 0)]
print(sample)
# [[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
#  [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, this is simply sorting the columns in reverse lexographic order?

```py
import numpy as np

sample = np.array([
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
])

sample[:, np.lexsort(-sample[::-1])]
```

output:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Wow! I did not make the connection in my head. Yes, indeed! I already accepted another answer but this one is great

Comment: I think there's something wrong with this solution. When I apply it to larger matrices, it returns an answer that can't be correct. I can tell because the number of 1s in the first row is 6 but the result has a first row with only 5 consecutive 1s.

Comment: Ah! I think the missing ingredient is we want `np.lexsort(-indicators[::-1])` since lexsort uses the last row as the primary key, the second to last row as the secondary key, etc. whereas I want the first row as the primary key, the second row as the secondary key

Comment: `sample[:, np.lexsort(-sample[::-1])]` matches the other solution for all test matrices I have.

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer I can update the answer with that interpretation if you don't mind?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert them to decimal and get the sorted order.

```
>>> mul = 2 ** (np.arange(arr.shape[0])[::-1]).reshape(1, -1)
>>> mul
array([[2, 1]], dtype=int32)
>>> order = np.argsort(mul @ arr).squeeze()[::-1]
>>> order
array([1, 0, 2], dtype=int64)
>>> arr[:, order]

array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```